# Rails Routes - Prevent accessing same controller#action through different urls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've noticed that when defining routes in the routes.rb file, you can actually access the same controller#action you defined in a different way.

For example:

```
map.connect "post/show/:id/:tag_title", :controller => "post", :action => "show", :requirements => {:id => /\d+/}
```

This means you can access post#show by going to

```
server.com/post/show/1234/tag_title-whatever
```

But you can also access post#show by going to

```
server.com/post/show?id=1234&tag_title=tag_title-whatever
```

It's a simple case, but you get the idea. Wouldn't this cause problems with search engines? If I'm not wrong, those 2 urls could potentially be taken as duped pages.

Is there a way to prevent this, like telling Rails to access the defined routes **only** the way they're defined?

Comment: if the route were post/:id/show than the alternate query string method wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to access something doesn't mean that it will be indexed by Google. All Rails helper functions use the `/post/show/..` links unless told differently. As long as you don't link to the specified resource, the likelihood of Google spidering the content is very slim.

That being said, I'm not even sure it would matter if they did end up indexing it.